# CSS3 animation onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two figures, one blue and one red. I have four buttons which uses JavaScript to switch CSS rules of the blue and red square.

The problem is that when I hit the "play red" button to start animate the red square, it vanish. I have checked through the code but I don't know what I have missed here.

The second problem occurs when Im using left/right button to rotate the blue square. When I hit it the first time it rotates. But whenever I hit the left/right button again it resets to the starting position and then rotates the 60 degrees again. My ambition here is to disable that reset of position. So if you hit right/left button twice the blue square should now have rotated 120 degrees.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pbukq2vu/

Right button
:

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('blue').classList.remove('rotateright', 'rotateleft');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('rotateright');    
    },100)

});
```

Left button:

```
document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('blue').classList.remove('rotateleft');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('blue').classList.add('rotateleft');        
    },100)
});
```

Play red button:

```
document.getElementById('button3').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('red').classList.add('animate');
});
```

Stop red button:

```
document.getElementById('button4').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('red').classList.remove('animate');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the two classes with css

```
#red {
    background-color:#ffaaaa;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border:thin;
    border-color:#000;
    border-width:1px;
    -webkit-transition: left 3s; 
    transition: left 3s;
    left:10px;
}
.animate {
    left: 100px !important;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbukq2vu/1/)

Comment: I forgot to add that the red square is suppose to move from it's position to the right and then move slowly back to it's original position and the loop is set to infinite until you hit the stop button. You will see what I mean if you check the css-rules I applied to the elements.

 I tried to add infinite to this example but it did not work. Could you show me how it could be done?

As well, did you have a solution to why the blue acts the way it does?
Thanks!